# What is the difference between "do something a number of times in a day" and "do something a number of times a day"?

Tags: prepositions

Tell me please what is the difference between *in a day* and *a day* in the following context.

> I practice my English five times **in a day**.
>
> I practice my English five times **a day**.

Comment: We just don't say "in a day" there. This can be found online and would you please show your own effort. Thanks.

Comment: As @Lambie points out, we don't [normally] include the preposition in *present* tense contexts like this. But in *past* tense contexts, (1) *They made love five times **in** a day* implies they only did so *on one specific day* (which would often be more emphatically expressed as *...five times in **one** day*). Whereas prepositionless (2) *They made love five times a day* strongly implies they only did so *repeatedly / habitually*.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is subtle, yet significant.

> I practice English five times in a day

This indicates that **one** day in the present time I practiced English five times.

> I practice English five times a day

This indicates that I **regularly** practice English five times a day.

Answer (score 0):

@Karlomanio is correct - except that the first example should be

> I *practiced* English five times in a day.